# Simplest solution to load foreignkey model with parent

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app which we are in the process of normalizing some contact details out of a bunch of different models. That said, this data still is used every time these different models are used, and I want to avoid a bunch of n+1 issues.

Is there a simple flag or something like that I can add to the foreignkey field, or something?

The only other idea I have is - on all of the different model's Managers, I override the filter, get, etc. methods to automatically tack on the

```
select_related('contact')
```

value.

Ideas?

Comment: Hmm, maybe add them as `OneToOne` to your existing model?

Comment: ah! so one to one always loads with the parent model (i.e. the one with the model as a ForeignField/OneToOne)? I actually need to use the same contact on multiple records...

Comment: Well then it should be ForeignKey by extract some info to a different model if multiple objects would link to one contact. I don't think it would make any difference because you are still doing `obj.contact` to get contact, right?

Comment: No, one to one doesn't do that. You need `select_related`.

Comment: yes, after the filter/get calls I use the object with a obj.contact to access the data. can I Chain select_related calls? if I add select_related before returning the manager, will that cause any subsequent call to select_related to fail?

Comment: select_related is cumulative and fine to chain.

Comment: @DanielRoseman awesome! thanks for adding that info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually go with overriding the get and filter methods to tack on the select_related. There are some old discussions regarding old Django versions, but as of now (1.8) you can call select_related multiple times and the framework correctly handles the duplicates.

Here are the overrides:

```
def get(self, **kwargs):
    """
    overwriting get to always include the contact information
    """
    return super(ParentRecordManager, self).select_related(
        'contact'
    ).get(**kwargs)

def filter(self, **kwargs):
    """
    overwriting filter to always include contact in the filter
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    return super(ParentRecordManager, self).select_related(
        'contact'
    ).filter(**kwargs)
```